# Oracle Row fetch within limit

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to fetch data between 10000 to 20000 rownum i have made this query

```
SELECT xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROWNUM >10000 AND ROWNUM<=20000
```

but above query is not working but when i change query to

`SELECT xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROWNUM >0 AND ROWNUM<=20000`
it works fine

what am i missing..?

Comment: What is your `Oracle database version`? In Oracle `12c`, you have the new `TOP-n` query using `FETCH`.

Comment: Oracle database version 10g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) FROM (select t.*, rownum rw from TABLENAME t) 
WHERE  rw>10000 AND rw<=20000
```

Rownum is calculated when Oracle retrieves the result of the query. That's why a query `select * from some_table where rownum > 1` never returns anything.

In addition, without ORDER BY it doesn't make sense to get rows between 10000 and 20000. You might as well get the first 10000 (as rows are unsorted the result is unpredictable - any row can be the first).

From Oracle documentation:

> For each row returned by a query, the ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a
>   number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a
>   table or set of joined rows. The first row selected has a ROWNUM of 1,
>   the second has 2, and so on.
>
> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer
>   are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
```

> The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the
>   condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and
>   is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows
>   subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned.

Comment: @jalil there are other options, for example analytic functions. But I think it's slow because of xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) which processes 10000 rows

Comment: @jalil In addition, without ORDER BY it doesn't make sense to get rows between 10000 and 20000. You might as well get the first 10000 (as rows are unsorted the result is unpredictable)

Answer (score 1):

`rownum` doesnot stay in any table It generates run time so when ever you run any `sql` statement then only for that time `rownum` will generate so you can't expect that you can use row num in `between` close.

Comment: I have converted query to SELECT xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000 but still not working

Comment: but SELECT xml_to_string(XMLRECORD) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 20000 working fine